# Cakephp 3.0: rewrite .htaccess rule to allow new folder access?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-3.0

I'm using cakephp 3.0 and I'm facing a problem. I upload my site on server on root level, where I place some demos which I can use for other purpose. Now issue is that when I access my site with domain name then it is working fine. But if I give any folder name which is placed on root level which is not the part of my site and is indiviual part of site. Then it is not accessible.

Below is my folder structure of root level

[image]

There a single folder named `gallery` is a demo. How can I allow this folder to access like this `http://hostname.com/gallery` or any other new folder.

My `.htaccess` file code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me on this issue which is more appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [The webroot folder _should be_ your apache document root](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production). What you have at the moment is [a development install](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#development-server) - if you modify your root .htaccess file you are quite likely to make sensitive files accessible to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your "gallery" folder under "webroot".

Comment: No, I can't do this. have you any idea for this?

Comment: Create a link to the gallery folder under webroot?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's worked for me.

create the .htaccess file in "gallary" folder with following content.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>
```

and try with URL http://server_name.com/gallary

You have access for that folder and files.

Thanks.